# Parse.com not returning emailVerified value on User object

Tags: parse-platform

I've set up my app to enable email verification and the emails come through fine. Trouble is, when I make a call to retrieve a User object, either with Parse.User.current() or by querying by id, the response does not contain the emailVerified field. I can't therefore check if the user is email verified or not.

I've tried this both in client side code and in cloud code with the same result.

You can try this out in your own code with a very simple snippet in the console:

```
var user = Parse.User.logIn("your_username", "your_password", {
  success: function(user) {
    console.log(user)
  }
});
```

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/parseusercurrent-doesnt-pull-all-the-data  explains how to get user field values

Comment: Note that if the value is undefined, it will not be the logged user. Set it to a value from the data browser and try your code again.

Answer (score 0):

That field seems to be protected, the only solution I can think of would be to query for where the value is true using some variant of `where` and check if you get a user back or not. If user is null, they haven't verified their email.